# simple git checkout <earlier-commit> , cwd files not change

Tags: git

I made a few changes, committed.

Then simply wanted to go back to an older commit on master.

The older files are showing on gitk.

But in the working directory, its the newer files.  Why isnt the checkout reverting my files?

I simply did git checkout  .

What am I missing or doing wrong?

(scared to do a git checkout master because the situation is muddled )

-thanks

Comment: Show us the responses to your commands. I'm betting the checkout was rejected for some reason... you may have modified files not checked in

Answer (score 0):

All a `checkout` command will never destroy changes in the working directory.  Instead it will move the head and do a safe update to the working directory (only replacing unmodified files).  If you want your working directory to look exactly like the `HEAD` of master branch then use reset

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard
```

Note that this will destroy any unsaved changes in your work space so be sure you want to run this command

Comment: hi, thanks for the response:  not sure what happened, but 1. additional/new files I was seeing on the remote were simply not tracked